# Making lower matrices values to be blank

Tags: matrix

In triangles generated when doing reserving how can we make the lower part that comes out as 0 to be NA's or how do we replace the 0's on the lower side of the triangle to be blank or NA'S in r without doing it manually

Comment: can you take an example?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.